# How do I handle a controller action according to its ActionResult type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, wav, actionresult

I have an controller method:

```
public ActionResult(int audioId)
{
    byte[] bytes = getAudio(audioId);
    if (bytes != null) 
    {
        return new FileContentResult(bytes, "audio/wav");
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }
}
```

Now in my view, if it is the content, I want it to open in a new window and it will start whatever plug-in to play it (if available). But if it doesn't exist, I want it to stay on the page and pop-up a warning.

How do I go about doing this, or am I approaching this problem in a completely wrong manner?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using AJAX to make the request since you are returning a Json result.

Every server response, independent of the server-side technology has a "Content-Type" header which you can query for your desired result.

For example if you are using jQuery to make the request, you could do something like this:

```
$.get('PLACE_URL_HERE', function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    var type = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

    if (type === 'application/json')
    {
        // Show warning
    }
    else if (type == 'audio/wav')
    {
        // Open new window
    }
});
```